# Why is this text field not showing up when I do element.text?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am attempting to gather reviews from online sources using Selenium Chrome Webdriver. On TripAdvisor, reviews are cut short and hidden behind a "More" button but in the html code there is a class named 'postSnippet' that contains the remainder of the review. However, when I find these WebElements and get their text fields, they come up empty. My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver", options=options)
url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g60745-d321960-Reviews-Giacomo_s_Restaurant-Boston_Massachusetts.html'
driver.get(url)

ls = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('postSnippet')
print([item.text for item in ls])


>>> ['', '', '', '', '', '']
```

I even tried debugging by printing `driver.page_source` to look for discrepancies but it is visible that those text fields are indeed there. Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print([item.get_attribute('innerHTML') for item in ls])
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32301175/selenium-cant-get-text-from-span-element)